# Woher kommt die fragende Antwort "Okay?"?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, colloquial, loanword

Schon lange wird *"okay"* für *"abgemacht, einverstanden, in Ordnung"* in der deutschen Umgangssprache verwendet. Neuerdings hört man aber zunehmend *"okay"* als **Frage** formuliert, mit einer mir noch ungewohnten Betonung:

> "Du hast heute noch einen weiteren Termin erhalten" - "Okay?"
>   "Mit Jeans kannst Du unmöglich zum Vorstellungsgespräch" - "Okay?"
>   **Aber:** "Hol mir doch bitte die Unterlagen" - "Okay."

Wo hat diese o.k.-Frage ihre Wurzel? Ist sie auch im Englischen neu, oder nur in der eingedeutschten Form? Gibt oder gab es vielleicht keine analoge deutsche Formulierung (was erklären würde, wie es sich so rasch verbreiten konnte)?

Comment: Ich bin ein wenig verwirrt über die Frage. Du kannst doch jemanden fragen: "Ist das in Ordnung für dich?", verkürzt: "In Ordnung?", oder Neudeutsch: "Okay?". Wo ist jetzt die ungewohnte Betonung?

Comment: Zur Erläuterung der Bedeutung bei der angesprochenen Verwendung: Der Sprecher drückt damit aus dass er

1. überrascht ist

2. das gesagte zunächst einmal nicht kommentieren will weil er 

3. auf eine Erläuterung wartet.


Bei der Verwendung in dieser Bedeutung ist die Intonation als Frage  in aller Regel überdeutlich. Ich persönlich mag diese Benutzung des Wortes deshalb gar nicht.

Comment: Ein Gesprächspartner hat sich dieses Okay? in der letzten Zeit auch angeeignet. Es wird eingesetzt, wenn die Konversation ihn nervt und zeigt die Abneigung gegenüber dem Gesagten. Dieses Okay? ist eigentlich nur berechtigt, wenn vorher jemand seinen Satz mit "verstehste" beendet hat. Ansonsten ist es eine Beleidigung seines Gegenüber. Eigentlich ist es heute (2016) auch nur noch in unterentwickelten Sprachgegenden zu finden, alle anderen haben mal nachgedacht und sind zu gegenseitiger Achtung im Gespräch übergegangen.

Comment: Das ist einfach die gekürzte Frage: Ist das okay? > Okay?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich denke, die Phrase "Okay?" wird hier ähnlich genutzt wie ein langgezogenes "Jjaa?" und beinhaltet meist einen fragenden Gesichtsausdruck.

Es dient dazu, dem Gesprächspartner zu signalisieren, dass man das Gesagte zwar im Wortlaut verstanden hat (deshalb das bestätigende "okay" oder "ja"), aber noch mehr Informationen benötigt, um die vom Gesprächspartner vermutlich intendierte Bedeutung zu verstehen (daher die Frageform).

Je nach Betonung kann es auch als Bestätigung des wörtlich Gesagten mit einer ungläubigen bis ablehnenden Grundstimmung genutzt werden. Hier macht wirklich der Ton die Musik.

In Sachen Herkunft vermute ich ganz stark englischsprachige TV-Serien und Filme, bei denen das "okay" die deutsche Synchronisation mangels passender deutscher Alternativen überlebt hat.

Das Wort "okay" hat ja bereits im Deutschen neben "ja" eine Rolle bei der schnellen, nicht als Unterbrechung gedachten Bestätigung des bislang Gesagten eingenommen. Es könnte also danach graduell auch in diese Form der Nutzung hineingerutscht, oder aber direkt in dieser Bedeutung auf dem gleichen Wege aus dem Englischen übernommen worden sein.

Comment: Die Phrase kenne ich ähnlich, daher +1, häufiger höre ich das Okay mit einer langgezogenen zweiten Silbe weniger als Frage als als ungläubige (auch ablehnende) Bestätigung.

Comment: @OregonGhost danke, hab's mit eingebaut :-) Eigentlich bräuchte man hier eine Tonhöhen- und -Längen-Notation, um die verschiedenen Varianten zu unterscheiden. Gibt's sowas eigentlich, abgesehen von Buchstabenwiederholungen?

Comment: @Takkat, mehr als Vermutungen kann ich auch nicht bieten... ;-)

Comment: "*Bestätigung des wörtlich Gesagten mit einer ungläubigen bis ablehnenden Grundstimmung*" : +1